# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

Tags: apache-spark

It would be really appreciated if anyone can help sort it out the following path issue for me? I highly doubt this is related to missing path setting but don't know how can I fix it.

```
rxie@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin/java:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/rxie/Downloads/s                                                                                  park:/home/rxie/Downloads/spark/bin:/usr/bin/java
rxie@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark$ pyspark
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

rxie@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark$ spark-shell

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

rxie@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark$ pwd
/home/rxie/Downloads/spark

```
rxie@ubuntu:~/Downloads/spark$ ls
bin  conf  data  examples  jars  kubernetes  licenses  R  yarn
```

Updated with the PATH:

```
rxie@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/home/rxie/Downloads/spark:/usr/bin/java:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Comment: No, this is not duplicate, I followed the steps there and still receive the error and spark-shell cannot be started.

Comment: You have to include the bin directory also in `/home/rxie/Downloads/spark` so echo $PATH should return you `/home/rxie/Downloads/spark/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin`

Answer (score 2):

Try setting SPARK_HOME environment variable to ~/Downloads/spark

Comment: Thank you, it is there already and yet the error is thrown. OP updated above.